# Дружественная функция из другого класса

Tags: c++, классы

Не могу разобраться, как прописать классу дружественную функцию из другого класса. Проблема в том, что классы написаны в разных файлах. Вот код:

```
// файл Complex.h
#include "Float.h"
class Complex
{
private:
    Float Re, Im;
public:
    Complex(Float re, Float im);
    void readFloat(Float);
};
// файл Complex.cpp
#include "Complex.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Complex::readFloat(Float)
{
    cout << "Чтение из дружественной функции: " << Re.Num;
}
// файл Float.h
class Float
{
private:
    float Num;
public:
    Float(float num);
    friend void Complex::readFloat(Float);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не получается потому, что для объявления дружественного метода требуется полное определение `Complex`, ведь вы обращаетесь к его члену.

Самый простой вариант - сделать другом не метод, а весь класс `Complex`:

```
// файл Float.h
class Float
{
private:
   float Num;
public:
   Float(float num);
   friend class Complex;
};
```

Если, всеж таки, необходим именно дружественный метод, тогда нужно обеспечить чтобы полное определение `Complex` гарантированно происходило до определения `Float`. Это можно сделать, применив технику с предварительным объявлением (forward declaration) `Float` в файле Complex.h:

```
// файл Complex.h
// #include "Float.h"  // этот инклюд нужно убрать

class Float;  // предварительное объявление

class Complex
{
private:
   Float * Re;
   Float * Im;

public:
   Complex(Float & re, Float & im);
   ~Complex();

   void readFloat(Float &);
};

// файл Complex.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "Complex.h"
#include "Float.h"   // а здесь он нужен

void Complex::readFloat(Float&)
{
   std::cout << "Чтение из дружественной функции: " << Re.Num;
}

// файл Float.h
#include "Complex.h"  // мы обращаемся к членам Complex
                      // поэтому он должен быть объявлен заранее
class Float
{
private:
   float Num;
public:
   Float(float num);
   friend void Complex::readFloat(Float&);
};
```

Техника работает следующим образом. Так как в файле Complex.h используются только указатели и ссылки на `Float` компилятору для вычисления размеров этих переменных и полей не требуется полное определение класса `Float`. Ведь размер указателей и ссылок фиксированный и заранее известен, вне зависимости от того, на что они указывают или ссылаются. Компилятору нужно только намекнуть что понимается под именем `Float` то есть что он класс, а не структура например. Компилятор не может работать с неизвестными именами. Из-за этой тонкости, можно убрать `#include "Float.h"` из файла Complex.h. Однако, когда мы обращаемся к членам `Float` необходимо его полное определение, поэтому в файле Complex.cpp обязательно наличие `#include "Float.h"`. После всего этого можно безопасно добавлять `#include "Complex.h"` в файле Float.h.

В результате всех этих манипуляций получается, что класс `Complex` всегда определен до `Float`, хотя объявлен `Float` раньше `Complex`. Ну и в итоге, как вы помните, строгий порядок определений классов позволяет нам законно объявить дружественным метод `Complex::readFloat`.

Comment: "сделать другом не функцию а весь класс" - нужен именно дружественный метод.
Но, к сожалению, данный вариант с предварительным объявлением у меня не сработал. Компилятор выдает ошибки:
error C2079: "Complex::Re" использует неопределенный class "Float"
error C2439: Complex::Re: не удается инициализировать член
и т.д. в том же духе. Есть ещё идеи?

Comment: в Complex.cpp добавили `#include "Float.h"`? В Complex.h только ссылки и указатели на Float?

Comment: Заработало. Я просто не сразу обратил внимания, что в классе Complex должны быть ссылки на объекты вместо самих объектов класса    Float    . А есть возможность организовать это так, чтобы в классе Complex полями были именно объекты?

Comment: По этому способу нет: читайте в конце ответа объяснение. Возможно есть другой способ, но мне в голову ничего не приходит.